# Eclipse embedded tomcat SNAPSHOT dependencies publishing

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, snapshot, eclipse-wtp

I'm working on web app which depends on an API. The API is still in SNAPSHOT version. I have both projects included in Eclipse and I noticed very strange behavior. When the API is build with `mvn clean install` I get jar with one size, but when I republish the web app, the my-api.jar that finishes in lib folder has greater size (see below).

target folder after `mvn clean install`

[image]

what I get after publishing in *WEB-INF\lib* folder

[image]

Can anyone explain what eclipse adds to the my-API jar when publishing the web app?

Versions used:

- Eclipse Kepler
- Eclipse WTP version: 3.4.0
- tomcat version: 6.0.29
- java version: 1.6.0_22
- mvn version: 3.2.5
- OS: Windows 7

Comment: usually while building jar maven will compress and it try to make it smaller than actual file size. when deploying the jar, server will decompress the file

Comment: @SasikumarMurugesan the one that is in lib is also compressed. Uncompressed files are much larger in size, e.g. for the particular my-api.jar, uncompressed version is 4.925.353